# How do I stop the jQuery-Clean plugin from deleting white spaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using this plugin: [link](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/)

like so:

```
$('.postListingDescription')
  .html(
    $.htmlClean(description, { 
      allowedTags : ["p", "b", "i", "u", "ul", "li", "a", "strong", "em", "br"] 
    })
  );
```

Unfortunately, this also deletes any white space, prohibiting any paragraph distinction and throwing everything together into one long string that doesn't return. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: It sounds like you would have to pre-parse the text and insert `<p>` tags where appropriate.  (Or, at a minimum, turn newlines into `<br />`.)

Comment: What is your value for `description`?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no options available the easiest thing is to replace this (line 485 of jquery.htmlClean.js):

```
function textClean(text) {
        return text
            .replace(/&nbsp;|\n/g, " ")
            .replace(/\s\s+/g, " ");
    }
```

to this:

```
function textClean(text) {
            return text
        }
```

But again, you should never use spaces to control your layout.
so what you can do is to replace all &nbsp with a `<p>` tag like mention in comments:

```
$this.html().replace(/\s\s+/g, '<p></p>')
```

Comment: I think `replace(/\s+/g, " ")` is exactly what the OP does not want

Comment: @Bergi, I think you might be right. I've updated my answer to remove both cases.